# É possível chamar uma Procedure em Consultas Programadas (Schedule Queries) no Big Query?

Tags: bigquery

Eu tentei de diversas formas chamar uma Procedure através desse interessante recurso do Big Query para agendamento de consultas. Se for possível a chamada de Procedures através desse recurso, será uma grande oportunidade de trabalhar de diversas formas com os dados no Big Query.

Já tentei chamar essa procedures de diversas formas, em resumo:

```
CALL project.schema.procedure()
CALL schema.procedure()
CALL procedure()
```

Peço uma ajuda!!!! Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Este recurso esta disponível no Bigquery e funciona bem, basta criar uma nova aba de consulta, colocar a sua chamada e clicar no botão de programação

**Veja:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém é importante ressaltar que o nome da função ou da procedure deve estar com o caminho completo e não apenas o nome como você colocou:

```
CALL `data-analytics-sandbox-dev.data_analytics_utils.SPC_GENERATE_REVENUE_DEF`();
```

Uma vez que faça isto basta adicionar os dados de execução e ser feliz. :)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Depois é só acompanhar a execução:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]